# Creating a Service with automator, caffeinate

Tags: terminal, bash, automator, sleep-wake

First of all, sorry for my english, not a native speaker.
Since I'm a bit fed up opening Termninal and `^C` I want to create a shortcut for activating `caffeinate -d` on my Mac OS X 10.11
I've been trying a simple Automator Service but with my noob skills it doesn't work.

This is the settings:
I chose Service as type of document

Library->Utilities->Run Shell Script
Service receives: `no input`
in: `any application`
Shell: `/bin/bash`
Pass input: `to stdin`

```
CAFFEINATECHECK=`ps | grep caffeinate | cut -d ' ' -f7,8`
if [ $CAFFEINATECHECK == 'caffeinate -d' ]; then
killall caffeinate
else
caffeinate -d
fi
```

Problem is that such a short scrip keeps running with no response and I have to stop it after a minute
I hope someone could give me any tips necessary

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're trying the check to see if `caffeinate` is running and terminate it if it is, or start it if it isn't, then I'd use:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [[ $(pgrep caffeinate) == "" ]]; then
    caffeinate -d &
else
    pkill caffeinate
fi
```

Comment: That surely is more elegant than my first draft. At first your code haven't worked, it kept running like mine for longer than it should, but I remembered reading somewhere that Automator doesn't work well with '&' AAAND INDEED it works (workflow completed in 0,218 seconds) by removing that out of the equation. Thanks alot, much appreciated

Comment: I experienced it before that a working bashscript wasn't running inside Automator environment. I still wonder what was that didn't let my code works smoothly afterall.